# ServiceStack Breaking Change in 4.0.22.0, CredentialsAuthProvider.OnAuthenticated now returns something

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I updated to version 4.0.22.0 this afternoon, and the OnAuthenticated method of class CredentialsAuthProvider now has a return type of ServiceStack.Web.IHttpResult.  I am unsure what to return in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's primarily for validation/error handling where you can return a redirect or a customized error HTTP response.

But for normal successful responses you can just return `null`.